# Running function based on different column values

Tags: r, average, plyr

I'm sure something similar has been asked, but I'm kind of new to R and can not find something that works. I'm using the forecast package to create a moving average from a year's worth of data. I would like run this function:

```
CityColl$cnt_ma <- ma(CityColl$clean_cnt, order=7)
```

But separately for each city.

I've tried split and apply functions something like this:

```
CityColl$cnt_ma <- ddply(CityColl, .(city), ma(CityColl$clean_cnt, order=7))
```

But this seems to be very wrong...

```
       start_time       city clean_cnt
   <date>      <chr>        <int>
     1 2016-01-01     Boston          242
     2 2016-01-01    Chicago          935
     3 2016-01-01 Washington         3220
     4 2016-01-01     Philly          639
     5 2016-01-02     Boston          221
     6 2016-01-02    Chicago         1421
     7 2016-01-02 Washington         4922
     8 2016-01-02     Philly          549
     9 2016-01-03     Boston          245
     10 2016-01-03    Chicago         1399
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also include the names of any packages that you are using. `ma` is not a base R function.

Comment: The example in the duplicate can perfectly be applied here:
`CityColl$MA <- ave(CityColl$clean_cnt,CityColl$city,FUN=function(v)as.numeric(ma(v,order=7)))`

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much for your help and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require(data.table)
require(forecast)

setDT(CityColl)

CityColl[, ma(city, order = 7), by = city]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this produces an error         

        "Warning in storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
Error in filter(x, w) : 'filter' is longer than time series"

Comment: @richardb: that's because you're using order=7 with a series of 2 or 3 values (yes, when you split by city you get only 2/3 values...)

Comment: The data I have is for a year, I simply provided a small sample of what the data looks like. Having never posted a question before, is there a better way to show this?

Comment: @richardb: your example is ok, maybe you can change order (e.g. order=3) and reduce the number of different cities to increase the series for each value, but your question is clear.